# Location Based Alarm on iOS

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, alarm

Yup. I fell asleep on the train and missed my stop. So next time I was *smart* and thought that I would set an alarm. Then I went to sleep with the alarm set for 6:09 instead of 8:09. So I missed the train stop yet again. Let me reiterate: ***smart***.

Instead of dealing with setting an alarm for a different time every time I get on the train and then either waking up early (because the train, as we know, is **always** late), forgetting to set it, or setting it for the wrong time.

---

**I am looking for a location based alarm app.** I know that location based reminders in the **Reminder app already exist** but they only show up on your screen and don't make any sound when silent is on.

I need an app that will be similar to the default Clock app alarms that will **sound even if the phone is on silent**. Additionally, I would like to **ring until I press stop**, ensuring that I am awake.

Comment: If in UK look at national rail app it has a wake you up setting for just this. It also uses the actual running time not just the timetabled one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into both [OmniBuzz](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/omnibuzz-gps-alarm-for-transit/id1076106050?mt=8) and [SleepyMe](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sleepyme-your-location-based-alarm-clock/id922506526?mt=8); they're both free IOS app which seems to provide the functionality you want. I've not personally used either before but I have a friend who gets the train to work at a ridiculous hour every day and raves about OmniBuzz.

From what others have said about SleepyMe; it seems that the app currently only supports audible alarms (i.e. no option for vibration only) which may be a concern if you don't want to irritate other passengers.

Let's hope you never miss your stop again!

Best wishes, Tom

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy solution to this. Set reminders and use location based alert. Set location when you arrive at home. Set time of alert to 6 am or whenever you want. Choose repeat everyday and in principle it should work. Please set sound notification to a more loud tone from Settings>Sound and Haptics. Hope this helps. Good luck! L!

[image]